# Netbeans 6.5 debug issue

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans6.5

I am debugging the following lines of code

---

```
    if (var.getvar2() != var3) {
           var4.add(var);
    } else {
           isNeeded= true;
           if (incomingPublishedDate.compare(modifiedDate) < 0) {
               importNeeded = true;
           } else {
               var4.add(var);
           }
   }
```

---

Here `var.getvar2()` and  `var3` are of type `Long`.
While debugging, when the condition goes like

```
10000 != 10000
```

the `if` should evaluate to `false`. But from the first `if`, the next Step Over goes to

```
var4.add(var);
```

and the next Step Over goes to `var4.add(var);`

Is this a Netbeans bug? Or is it with the `Long` comparision.

I am using **Netbeans IDE 6.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare objects by value. That comparison would only be true if the two references compared refer to the same object. Instead use:

```
if (! var.getvar2().equals(var3)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Correct. As thus, this is not a Netbeans issue, it is a user-issue.

Comment: just to confirm, then why does the step over from var4.add(var); go to var4.add(var); inside the else part?

Comment: Oh I see what the real problem is. Add some dummy System.out.println("blah"); lines below both adds, and see if they are actually called by the code.
Or copy in the whole function body, you might have a problem with your opening/closing brackets (I don't see how though).